# This might make you happy

Tags: word, rhyme

> Born in 1980s with unknown beginning
>
> Grew up as a slang, I have several meanings
>
> From either of my sides, I look the same
>
> But look from the top ,I am  airplane

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> lol (laughing out loud)

Born in 1980s with unknown beginning

> The first instance of this abbreviation is in a 1980s Usenet discussion

Grew up as a slang, I have several meanings

> Can also mean "lots of love" among other things

From either of my sides, I look the same

> It's a palindrome

But look from the top ,I am airplane

> Looks like a [TIE fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIE_fighter) from Star Wars :)
>
>  (from OP:) When you turn LOL upside down, you get 707, which is an airplane.

Title: This might make you happy

> People laugh when they're happy

Comment: I remember when (ROT13) Zl zhz'f sevraq cnffrq njnl, naq fur fnvq "yby" gb cnl ure erfcrpgf. Rirelbar pnyyrq ure penml hagvy fur fnvq vg jnf zrnag gb zrna "ybgf bs ybir". Nygubhtu gur cnffvat bs ure sevraq vf fnq gb qvfphff, V zhfg nqzvg, guvf fgbel vf n yvggyr shaal :D

Comment: Except for the Airplane explanation @jafe.

Comment: And you are a great puzzle solver, I noticed

Comment: well the airplane explanation certainly made me happy! :D

Comment: @jafe  LOL from the top looks like 7O7. Please edit your answer which is correct.

Comment: @DEEM I see. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> **[E.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial)** ?

`Born in 1980s with unknown beginning`

> The movie **E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial** was created in **1982** and nobody knows where the alien (referred to as ET) was born, itself.

`Grew up as a slang, I have several meanings`

> Grew up as **E.T.** which could mean [many things](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/ET).

`From either of my sides, I look the same`

> Yes, pretty much.

`But look from the top, I am an airplane`

> This might refer to **space exploration** because ET is an **extra-terrestrial** (and "looking from the top" might refer to looking from **space**). In particular, this might be referring to **space shuttles** which can look like an airplane (e.g. [here](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/edu_shuttle_launch_sts-117.jpg) and [here](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/2010-4649.jpg)).

---

**Title:**

`This might make you happy`

> **ET** might stand for **Easy to Talk to**, I suppose, which is ironically unlike ET.